# gretap tunnel return traffic not being handled

Tags: centos, centos7, iproute2, gre

I'm using iproute2 to add a GRE layer 2 tunnel with a vlan tag as shown below.

```
ip link add name gre1 type gretap local 10.0.0.2 remote 8.8.8.8
ip link add name gre1.100 link gre1 type vlan proto 802.1q id 100
ip link set gre1 up
ip link set gre1.100 up
dhclient -v gre1.100
```

Using tcpdump I see the encapsulated return packets coming to the "physical" interface(eth0) but not either of the gre interfaces. What am I missing?

centos 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

derp

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --direct --add-rule ipv6 filter INPUT 0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
```